# How to rename or open a file in windows?

Tags: windows

I am working with files having such name:

2019-01-11 17:39:51.707256-Synchroniation_Parameters_Legitimate.log

But I am blocked I can't open, delete or rename it. I have the problem displayed in the figure. I have tried many solution by changing the drive, using the command prompt. But it was the same situation all the time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FYeJ.png)

Comment: Was the file created by a Unix application?

Comment: @Anders yes it was created in linux environment

Answer (score 0):

The filename contains a `:` (colon) which is not valid in Windows applications. Certain Unix tools (and the Linux on Windows mode (WSL) in Windows 10) are able to create files with illegal characters. The best option is to delete/rename the file in the same environment/application it was created.

You can also try to use cmd.exe to delete the file.

- Delete it using the short name: Find the short name by executing `dir /X *` in the directory where the file is and then delete it with the short name (`del 2019-01~1.log` or whatever the short name is). Short names can be turned off and then this trick will not work.

or

- Delete it by bypassing the Win32 namespace checks: Prefix the **full path** with `\\?\`: `del "\\?\c:\whatever\2019-01-11 17:39:51.707256-Synchroniation_Parameters_Legitimate.log"`. This trick is documented in [KB 320081](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume).

Comment: Colon is not reserved in all file systems on Windows (e.g. a VirtualBox shared folder allows it). Microsoft's file systems reserve it since it has a special significance for [named streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-streams) in file systems that support them, such as NTFS.

Comment: File streams have the form "filename:streamname:streamtype". Note that the colon is not part of the base file name. For a regular file open, the assumed stream type is "$DATA", so we only need the stream name, e.g. "filename:streamname". All regular files have at least an anonymous stream, which is just "filename". Obviously "51.707256-Synchroniation_Parameters_Legitimate.log" is not a valid stream type.

Comment: The runtime library's path translation and normalization has no bearing on this problem, so using a path prefixed by "\\?\" (i.e. an extended local-device path) is of no help. Path translation operates in user mode before making a system call, such as `NtCreateFile`. By the time the system sees device paths, they are all in native local-device form, i.e. "\??\<device name>[\<device path>]". The only time the runtime library translation cares about colons in the final path component is for reserved DOS device names in logical drive-letter paths, such as "C:\Temp\nul: .spam" -> "\\.\nul".

Comment: The characters that need to be reserved by a file system are null, backslash, slash, and the five wildcard characters: asterisk, question mark, less-than sign (`DOS_STAR`), greater-than sign (`DOS_QM`), and quotation mark (`DOS_DOT`). The spec for `NtQueryDirectoryFile` supports wildcard pattern matching to filter directory listings, but has no way to escape the wildcard characters, so they have to be reserved if implemented. Not implementing them would break the expected behavior of WinAPI `FindFirstFile`, but allowing colon, pipe, and ASCII control characters doesn't break the API.

Comment: A notable exception is the named-pipe file system, which allows all characters in names, even backslash since it only supports a root directory. It even allows null since NT uses counted strings instead of null-terminated strings, but using null in a name is asking for problems.